# SSRS - Displaying the datasource server name in your report

Tags: reporting-services

In my ssrs report I'd like to display the name of the server used by my data source. Is there any way to access and display this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add it as part of your query (or create a new query for it) using the `@@ServerName` built in function:

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS ServerName, *
FROM MyTable
```

or as a standalone query in its own dataset:

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS ServerName
```

Then you just use the following formula in your text box:

```
=First(Fields!ServerName.Value, "DataSet1")
```